# While using bash script to edit file works but at last shows error as "sed: can't read "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am editing a file using bash script as below.

I have the file 'input.env' and I am editing certain key-value pairs using the below code

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
INPUTFILEPATH="/config/input.env"
DEVICEID=$(uuidgen)
echo "Device Id generated is: $DEVICEID"
sed -i "s/^DEVICE_ID.*/DEVICE_ID=$DEVICEID/" $INPUTFILEPATH

echo -n "Select the Environment: "
cat << EOF
1. ABC
2. DEF
EOF
read ENV

case $ENV in 
  1)
    DPSHOST="abc.com"
    ACTIVEMQURL=178.25.11.5 
    ;;

  2) 
    DPSHOST="def.com"
    ACTIVEMQURL=178.27.1.9
    ;; 
  *) 
    echo "wrong choice of env and DPS HOST, ACTIVEMQURL not set" 
    ;; 
esac

echo "Setting DPSHOST as $DPSHOST"
sed -i "s/^DPS_PROVISIONING_HOST.*/DPS_PROVISIONING_HOST=$DPSHOST/" $INPUTFILEPATH

echo "Setting ACTIVEMQURL as $ACTIVEMQURL"
sed -i "s/^ACTIVEMQ_URL.*/ACTIVEMQ_URL=$ACTIVEMQURL/" $INPUTFILEPATH

echo "ALL ENV VARIABLES SET"

echo "Start to run setup"
sudo bash /setup_script/setup.sh
```

The last command could not run which triggers 'setup.sh'. All the variables are set right as per script but the error is shown as

```
Start to run setup
sed: can't read ../config/input.env: No such file or directory
sed: can't read ../config/input.env: No such file or directory
grep: ../config/input.env: No such file or directory
grep: ../config/input.env: No such file or directory
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Where is `..` coming from? That's not in the script.

Comment: The errors are coming from `setup.sh`, not the script you posted.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that's right. Path to the setup.sh was given wrongly. But still, the errors for input.env does not make any sense here. That file path is right.

Comment: Then `ls ../config/setup.env` should work.

Comment: Unrelated problem: if the user enters something other than "1" or "2", it gives an error message but then goes ahead and edits the input file (storing blank values) and tries to run setup.sh. It should probably exit instead of continuing.

Comment: No, the errors are coming from `setup.sh`. Don't you see that they're after `echo "Start to run setup"`?

Comment: Change `setup.sh` so it uses an absolute path for `setup.env`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the file exists and it's writeable before attempting to edit it

```
if [[ -w "$INPUTFILEPATH" ]]
then
    echo "Setting DPSHOST as $DPSHOST"
    sed -i "s/^DPS_PROVISIONING_HOST.*/DPS_PROVISIONING_HOST=$DPSHOST/" $INPUTFILEPATH

    echo "Setting ACTIVEMQURL as $ACTIVEMQURL"
    sed -i "s/^ACTIVEMQ_URL.*/ACTIVEMQ_URL=$ACTIVEMQURL/" $INPUTFILEPATH
else
    echo "Cannot write $INPUTFILEPATH"
fi
```